# HERE map tile api with Leaflet, how to get and display the correct copyright information?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, here-api

Using the the HERE map tile api with Leaflet, how to get and display the correct copyright information?

Source. https://developer.here.com/rest-apis/documentation/enterprise-map-tile/topics/resource-copyright.html

You need to query the copyright resource of the same base url you are using. OK. But how to match the json bounding boxes (all of them) in the query reply with the map tiles used, and update the copyrigt information as the user navigates and zooms the map?

I need javascript code examples for this, HERE's homepage offers none.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never used Leaflet but from their docs it seems you're looking for [LatLngBounds](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#latlngbounds).

Convert all the bounding boxes from the copyright JSON response to LatLngBounds and store them (best with the copyright string somehow associated). Then you can ask for the L.map(...).[getBounds()](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-getbounds) whenever [zoomend](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-zoomend) or [moveend](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-moveend) fires and call intersect on all the copyright bounds which are valid at the current zoom level (see the JSON response, some copyright are only valid from e.g. zoom 9 - 20). The ones that do [intersect](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#latlngbounds-intersects) belong in the copyrights.

Sorry, I don't have code samples but you should be able to work it out from this.

Comment: Sounds like it would be an interesting plugin to have (but it does not seem to exist for now unfortunately?). Maybe a little bit tricky regarding performance of always checking against all of these bounding boxes all over the world...